# Downloading library files options as external user

Tags: powershell, csom, authentication, external-users

I'm a member of a SharePoint site as an external user and have access to a document library with lots of files/folders. I want all of this content downloaded for offline usage and sharing. I'm unable to sync this library via OneDrive I believe because I am an "external" user [OneDrive Sync Error](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sync/cant-add-folder-right-now#use-an-internal-account-to-sync-content) and it appears sync works only with internal accounts.

Besides manually downloading the files, can I download this content programmatically as an external user? Assume I only have access via my credentials which requires MFA/2FA - so no service accounts, App accounts, etc.

C# CSOM, PowerShell, etc. are all options for me if it's even feasible as an external user with MFA.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, you should be aware that the Synchronizing content using an external or guest user is currently **not supported** by OneDrive. so the external users with Microsoft account can't sync the SharePoint library.

> Read more at [Restrictions and limitations in OneDrive and SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Also, if the site admin set the "`Allow items from this site to be downloaded to offline clients`" to `NO` in the site settings, the external users will not be able to download files!

[image]

**As a workaround**, If you already can download the files, you can simply select all files and hit `Download` button to download all files from a document library in modern libraries.